# Emacs escape key

Tags: emacs, keyboard, key-bindings

Currently, if I press `C-h c`, then trice press `ESC` key on keyboard I get result

```
ESC ESC ESC (translated from <escape> <escape> <escape>) runs the command keyboard-escape-quit
```

What the difference between `ESC` and `<escape>` and how can I use this difference to make more keybindings?

Comment: I believe they're the same.  It's just a notational difference

Comment: It's ok to accept your own answer (click the checkmark beside your answer). This is also helpful for others, as it marks the question as 'answered'.

Answer (score 11):

Found solution in `emacs` [mailing list archive](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2013-02/msg00255.html):

> The escape key usually is linked to the escape char, but the two
>   are different.  Under a tty, Emacs receives the exact same byte-sequence
>   from the terminal if you type the escape key or if you type C-[ (both
>   send the escape char).
>
> Under a GUI, on the other hand, Emacs can distinguish the two, so under
>   a GUI, the escape key doesn't send `?\e` (aka `ESC` for kbd) but `escape`
>   (aka `<escape>` for kbd) which is usually turned into a `?\e` via
>   function-key-map (i.e. only if there's no corresponding binding for the
>   key sequence with `escape`).
>
> Same thing happens with tab (i.e. TAB (aka `C-i`) vs tab) and return
>   (i.e. RET (aka `C-m`) vs return).